# Can I increase the scope of 'this' in the following example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In using a jquery callback, I found that 'this' isn't defined anymore. I've found a work around, which is to set 'this' to another variable. For example, like so:

```
function handler(DATA) {
       var myThis = this;

       $.post(
          'file.php',
          DATA,
          function() {

               // THIS where I need access to 'this', but its not available
               // unless I've used the 'myThis' trick above

          }
       );
}
```

It works like this, but I am always looking for 'the right way' or 'the better way' to do things.

Is this the best way? or is there another?

Comment: You probably want to throw a `var` in front of `myThis = this;` but the way you are doing it is common practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine. I do this all the time in my projects, especially with Ajax calls.

But, make sure to put `var` before `myThis`, or else it will be declared in global scope, which you most definitely don't want.

```
function handler(DATA) {
       var myThis = this;

       $.post(
          'file.php',
          DATA,
          function() {

               // THIS where I need access to 'this', but its not available
               // unless I've used the 'myThis' trick above

          }
       );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually had var in my code, but I didn't copy/paste for whatever reason :)  I was hoping there was a smoother, slicker way but there isn't always.

Answer (score 1):

I like using "self":

```
function handler(DATA) {
   var self = this;
   $.ajax({
      "url":"file.php",
      "type":"post",
      "data":DATA,
      "success":function() {
           // THIS where I need access to 'this', but its not available
           // unless I've used the 'myThis' trick above
      },
      "error":function(){
          alert("ERROR!")
      }
    });
}
```

you can also use jQuery's proxy method...but it would probably be overkill for this situation.

```
function handler(DATA) {
   var success = $.proxy(function(){
       // use "this" in this function to refer to the scope 
       // you were assigning to "myThis" in your example
   }, this);
   $.ajax({
      "url":"file.php",
      "type":"post",
      "data":DATA,
      "success":success,
      "error":function(){}
  });
}
```